# PHP redirecting to original URL after successful login

Tags: php

I'm not sure which is the best way to do this, so I would love to hear some ideas.

Ok, let's say we have this link/url => `www.myscript.com/clients.php?id=5`

If I try to open it, I get redirected to `www.myscript.com/login.php`, because I'm not logged in, and then when I get logged in I don't get redirected to original link/url `www.myscript.com/clients.php?id=5` as I would like to.

So what should I add to login.php to achieve such acting/working?

Keep in mind that URL migt be different such as:

```
- www.myscript.com/clients.php?id=5
- www.myscript.com/orders.php?invoice=125
```

etc...

Comment: You could store the URI in a `$_SESSION` variable in your "is the user logged in" checking code, then redirect back to it in your login auth code.

Comment: What are you using for sessions/logins? How are you forcing the redirect?

Comment: All I want to do is to get redirected to the original URL I entered after the log-in...

Comment: @MrGlass I have this in my dologin.php, which is executed when we submit form used in login.php.
`header ('Location: index.php');`
`exit ();`

Comment: @ProDraz That will redirect the user to the index after login. What redirects the user TO the login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to add a tracking value to your scripts, if you added this to all pages (or an element of your site which appears on every page...?)

```
<?php
session_start(); // only if you are not already using sessions - if you are, you don't need this line
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != 'login.php') && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $_SESSION['oldURL'])) {
    $_SESSION['oldURL']     = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
}
?>
```

Then in your login page, where you want the redirect you can use `$_SESSION['oldURL']`

Answer (score 2):

While doing the redirect to login.php

Pass the

```
urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])
```

as an argument like shown below.

```
login.php?return=clients.php%3Fid%3D5
```

On successful login, redirect the page to

```
urldecode($_GET['return'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (login successfull)
    header("Location: $storedURLvariable(www.myscript.com/orders.php?invoice=125)");
```

Answer (score -1):

In login.php, put something like:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;  // Wherever your user would actually be logged in.
```

Now, at the beginning of all the pages you want "only to be accessible when logged in", put:

```
if (!$_SESION['logged_in'])
{
     header("Location:/login.php");
     exit();
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. Redirecting to login is the easy part. Redirecting BACK to the page the user originally hit BEFORE getting sent to login is what the OP wants.